# returning firebase array returns tuple instead of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, javascript-objects

I'm querying from firebase realtime database, storing each result in an array, and returning this array. While the data is correct, I am not returning it in a type I want it to be in.

The code for this function is

```
exports.getprojects = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const uid = req.body.uid;
  var projectref = fref.child('projects');
  var projarr = [];

  // Make the promise object for query
  const projpromise = projectref.orderByChild('key').equalTo(uid).once('value');
  // Another Promise for pushing to array
  const pushpromise = projpromise.then(snap => {
    var proj_item = snap.val();

    // push to array
    projarr.push(proj_item);
    return proj_item;
  }).catch(reason => {
    console.log(reason)
    return res.json(400);
  })

  // Respond with array
  return pushpromise.then((proj_item) => {
    return res.json(200, projarr);
  }).catch(reason => {
    console.log(reason)
    return res.json(400);
  })
});
```

This function queries all the right data, but returns in format like this :

```
[
   {
    "project_id": {
        "project_title": "Test Project1",
        "project_type": "Long Term"
    },

    ... 
]
```

What I need is for this function to return in format like below :

```
{
   {
    "project_id": {
        "project_title": "Test Project1",
        "project_type": "Long Term"
   },

    ...
}
```

How can I achieve this? Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: That last snippet is not valid JSON, so it's impossible to construct it in JavaScript code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To turn your array into a JSON object with just the key-value pairs, do something like this:

```js
var array = [
    {"project_id": {
        "project_title": "Test Project1",
        "project_type": "Long Term"
    }},
    {"project_id2": {
        "project_title": "Test Project2",
        "project_type": "Medium Term"
    }},
    {"project_id3": {
        "project_title": "Test Project3",
        "project_type": "Short Term"
    }}
];

var result = {};

array.forEach(function(object) { 
  var key = Object.keys(object)[0];
  result[key] = object[key];
})

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! If I may ask, what is the difference between an array of JSON objects and JSON with simply key-value pairs? When I log both using typeof, I get object for both.